# reading JSON on Blackberry OS pre 6.0

Tags: json, blackberry, java-me

I am trying to implement web services within an app, and the response of the web serivce is in JSON. How is it possible to parse simple json without net_rim_json_org module of BBOS 6.0?

Answer (score 5):

For pre-6 BB OS people use [JSON ME](http://java.net/projects/meapplicationdevelopers/sources/svn/show/demobox/mobileajax/lib/json) lib.

Comment: Just make sure you exclude those third-party library files from the build for 6.0 and 7.0 otherwise you'll get errors due to conflicts with the native classes which use the same package and class names.