# Parsing JSON response in Blackberry

Tags: java, json, blackberry

I am getting a below JSON Response from the server please let me know how to parse this.
I only need

```
---------------------------7da7d113c0dea
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 338
Request-Id: 714a31e1-1b2c-4e10-8ce1-7b7c4204ff66
response-type: rfc_json
status-code: 200
processing-time: 74993


{"EXPORTING":{"OUT_CATEGORY_CODE_DESC":[{"CONTENT":"1","LIST_ID":"","DESCRIPTION":
"Business Area","DISABLED":""},{"CONTENT":"2","LIST_ID":"",
 "DESCRIPTION":"Industry","DISABLED":""},{"CONTENT":"5","LIST_ID":"",
  "DESCRIPTION":"Vendor","DISABLED":""}],
  "OUT_MESSAGE":"","OUT_SOLUTION_DETAILS":[],
   "OUT_SUBCATEGORY_SEARCH":[]},"IMPORTING": null}

    ---------------------------7da7d113c0dea--
```

i would like to retrive values OUT_CATEGORY_CODE_DESC[],OUT_SOLUTION_DETAILS":[] and OUT_SUBCATEGORY_SEARCH":[] . Do you have any sample code here?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288204/reading-json-on-blackberry-os-pre-6-0

Answer (score 1):

There is a package over on [JSON.org](http://json.org) called [`org.json.me`](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/) which is a port of `org.json` to Java ME.