# net_rim_json_org not found

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have created one application in j2me, I have used json parsing in that application. I can build it SUCCESSFULLY.

```
Parsing import: C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0/lib/net_rim_api.jar(net_rim_json_org.cod)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 3 seconds)
```

But when imported application on blackberry 9000 v5.0, and trying to open it it showing

```
net_rim_json_org not found
```

My question is, it's showing that net_rim_api.jar (net_rim_json_org.cod) imported but when I am trying on device its showing error - why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also faced this problem and have managed to solve like as described below.

**`package org.json.me`** is built-in in JDE 6.0.0 but not in JDE 5.0.0 or below.
So, you need to add that package yourself.
You can download the package from [github](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/).

If you want to write the same code for both **JDE 6** and **JDE 5** and make your application work on both JDE 6 and JDE 5, then you can rename that package to something like **`org.json.whatever`**   .... and in your code wherever you need to use **`org.json.me.JSONArray`** , **`org.json.me.JSONObject`** .... you just use **`org.json.whatever.JSONArray`**, **`org.json.whatever.JSONObject`** etc. Thus you can make your code JDE-version independent for JSON parsing.

More on json parsing in the SO question "[Json parser for Blackberry OS 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453618/json-parser-for-blackberry-os-5)"

Answer (score 2):

You have compiled your application with SDK 6.0 and are trying to launch it on device with SDK 5.0

```
SDK version == JDE version you have used.
```

Error you get means that device OS ver. 5.0 does not have this library, that exists in device OS ver. 6.0

Note that, if you compile your app with SDK 6.0 it will run properly on devices with OS versions 6.0 and 7.0, but not on devices with OS 5.0 and older.

Comment: net_rim_json_org is available on BlackBerry JDE v5.0?

Comment: I do not have installed JDE 5.0 on my computer, if you do, then check simulator folder of JDE 5.0. If there is a file "net_rim_json_org.debug" exists, then this file exists on the device with OS 5.0 as "net_rim_json_org.cod".

Answer (score 0):

In you build settings==> order and export, you are exporting that library or not. If not then please check the checkbox and your application works fine

Comment: i have used netbean, can you please explain your answer properly.

Comment: I am using eclipse, In Eclipse what I use to do that is....Right click on your project ==> Bulid Path ==> Configure Build Path ==> Order and Export, here your json library is showing, just checked the checkBox and save the settings.  ......I doesn't know about netbeans might be it is same for that also.

Comment: Go to its Properties -> Sources -> Compile tab and add all the JARs that you want to be included.