# Problems refactoring package on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm using org.json.me on my project(eclipse jde 7.0 on Mac).
To provide compatibility for jde 5.0, I re-factored the package name to org.json.compatibility. The problem is that after the refactoring eclipse don't recognize the import org.json.compatibility.
What Im doing wrong? I think, I didn't missing anything.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide compatibility for OS5 you will need to have a new BlackBerry project within Eclipse. Then you can include the source for org.json.me on the project build path, rather than needing to refactor the package name.

Comment: A new project compiled with jde 5.0? This is not possible on mac. 
Regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010484/net-rim-json-org-not-found

I can make a jde-version independent to JSON parsing.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, are you trying to create an app which runs on OS5 devices? If so, you must compile it against the OS5 JRE, otherwise it won't run.

Comment: Yeah, sadly to make work this release I need to build against OS5 on Windows ;(. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yeah, that figures, unfortunately BlackBerry development on a mac isn't particularly well supported. All the best! :)