# Error Starting Tag: Module 'net_rim_json_org' not found. on blackberry OS 5.0 (runs fine on OS 7)

Tags: json, blackberry

When I am running my app on an OS 7.0 device, it works fine, but on 5.0 it's throwing the error:

> Error Starting Tag:Module'net_rim_json_org'not found.

I tried to import packages in the same project, then again it's showing duplicate files error.  How to solve this so that i can run the same app for OS 7 and 5.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using some of the JSON classes that were added under `net.rim.json` in [BlackBerry OS 6.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/org/json/me/JSONObject.html).

So, if you build and run on OS 6.x or 7.x, it'll work fine.  But, those classes are missing on BlackBerry 5.0.

[See this answer for some JSON parsing options on OS 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7453946/119114)

If you want to keep one single code base, and just compile against 5.0, then pick one of the solutions in the last link, and don't use `net.rim.json.*`.

If you would prefer to build and deliver separate versions of your app (e.g. one for 5.0 and the other for 6.0+), then BlackBerry supports that.  Or, if you think your company will abandon support for 5.0 soon, but keep OS 6/7 for a while, and you also are taking advantage of other 6.0+ features, then maybe you are fine having two different versions of your JSON parsing code.

As always, keeping your parsing code well-*encapsulated*, so that it can be changed without affecting your entire app, is a good idea.