# Blackberry JSON parsing for BB OS version 5

Tags: json, parsing, blackberry

I need to parse a JSON string in my project, which runs on BB OS 5.
OS version 5 does not have JSON parsing inbuilt in it.
I have tried the code from the Knowledge Base article [Sample Code - Implementing JSON in your application](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Sample-Code-Implementing-JSON-in-your-application/ta-p/539659),  but it does not run on OS 5 either.

Can someone suggest a library or some jar file to parse JSON for BB OS 5.

Comment: first take the jar file from this below link https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/tree/master/src/main/java/org/json/me  which is provided by @Signature and add to your project. Implement like in 6.0

Comment: Searching StackOverflow for "+blackberry +json" turns up a number of similar questions already answered.  Among them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453618/json-parser-for-blackberry-os-5
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288204/reading-json-on-blackberry-os-pre-6-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey thanks Signare for your help. The jar dint work for me but importing the source files did. :) Initially I had imported the source files, but along with that I forgot to remove the BB json imports. Now it works fine... on all OS versions.

Got the source files from here https://bitbucket.org/liedman/json-me/src/501a54188df3/src/org/json/me

Answer (score 2):

This will help you - [Json](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/tree/master/src/main/java/org/json/me)

```
 String jsonStr = "{\"team\":\"india\",\"manager\":\"meSağlam\",\"year\":\"2012\"}";
```

Create a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

if you want to use the value of the "team" field which is "Bursaspor" then you should use your JSONObject like this:

```
obj.getString("team");
```

This call will return the string value which is "india".

Comment: Hi Signare.. Your above code will work fine for BB OS 6 and above, But it gives an error on OS 5 on launch, saying Module 'net_rim_json_org' not found.
I need to run it on BB OS ver 5.

Comment: if you need the jar file, then i will email you.

Comment: I tried the above code and tested it on simulators, it works for OS6 simulator, but not for OS 5 simulator. Are you sure you did not import any library or package for JSON parsing?

Comment: i used the json-me.jar library.

Comment: hey buddy.. sorry to bug u again... I imported the jar file in my project, but when I run the project it gives me an error  Error!: Duplicate definition for 'org.json.me.JSONArray' found in: org.json.me.JSONArray

Comment: remove the json classes. only import the jar file

Comment: but above my class I have to import

import org.json.me.JSONException;
import org.json.me.JSONObject;

Comment: you added https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/tree/master/src/main/java/org/json/me the java files to your project ?

Comment: I had added it initially, but it dint work. So now I do not have it in my source..